# Как парсить JSON с помощью GSON полученный Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, json, retrofit, pojo, яндекс-переводчик

Использую API Яндекс.Переводчика, и мне нужно получить доступные пары перевода (RU-EN и т.д.).

Для запросов использую `Retrofit2`, и для дессериализации `GSON`.

Переводчик возвращает JSON такого вида:

```
{ 
   "dirs":[  
      "az-ru",
      "be-bg",
      "be-cs",
      "be-de",
      "be-en",
        ...
   ],
   "langs":[  
      "af":"Африкаанс",
      "am":"Амхарский",
      "ar":"Арабский",
      "az":"Азербайджанский",
        ...
   ]
}
```

Для GSON нужно сделать POJO, и если для массива dirs все понятно:

```
    @SerializedName("dirs")
    @Expose
    private List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<String>();



    public List<String> getDirs() {
        return dirs;
    }
```

То для объекта langs, все не так ясно. Я пробовал делать POJO по телу JSON (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org), но у меня получается отдельный класс langs с каждым из значений langs, что меня не устраивает.

```
public class Langs implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("af")
@Expose
private String af;

public String getAf() {
return af;
}
...
```

Я бы не хотел делать статику (вдруг Яндекс добавить язык!).

Как мне быть? Я думаю, что можно как-то распарсить json без POJO, но не нашел рабочих примеров (скорее не смог разобраться) для retrofit.

Comment: Попробуйте тут псомттреть: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29128176/3212712

Comment: А в `Map<String, String>` не десериализуется?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо огромное! 
Все оказалось просто:
Добавил в свой POJO:

```
@SerializedName("langs")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, String> langs = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public Map<String, String> getLangs() {
    return langs;
    }

    public void setLangs( Map<String, String> langs) {
        this.langs = langs;
    }
```

И потом разбираю вот так:

```
public void onResponse(Call<DirectionTranslateJSON> call, Response<DirectionTranslateJSON> response) {

  Map<String, String> langs = data.getLangs();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : langsMap.entrySet()) {

                        resultTxt.setText(pair.getKey()+" : "+ pair.getValue());

                    }
```